# Mixin inhheritance for models in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-south, django-orm

Is there a way to build django models hierarchy like this?

```
class LikableObjectMixin(models.Model):
    # mixin for all likable objects: posts, photos, etc
    likers = models.ManyToManyField(Account)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save():
        super(LikableObjectMixin, self).save()


class Post(LikableObjectMixin, models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(_('Post'))
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='posts', blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Can south work with this kind of inheritance? Is this an appropriate way to build model hierarchy?

Django=1.5.1

Comment: It's enough `class Post(LikableObjectMixin)` since the other class already inherits from `models.Model`

Comment: I know, but this is just an example and I want to use this mixin for another models which can be inherited from another models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine. South will create proper m2m relations for all your models that inherit from your mixin. You don't even have to write `save` method explicitly. So:

```
class LikableObjectMixin(models.Model):
    likers = models.ManyToManyField(Account)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Post(LikableObjectMixin):
    message = models.TextField(_('Post'))
```